# Help with ～ようにそっとする

Tags: grammar, usage

I'd like help with this passage.

It is from the workbook 日本語総まとめN2:

> 「もちろん、試合前の練習や表情、試合後の様子などを知りたくないなどというつもりはありませんが、なるべく試合だけに集中できるよう、ファンへのサービスに気をつかわなくてもいい**ようにそっとして**あげられたら、と思わずにはいられないのです。」

The first part seems clear to me: "It's not that I don't wanna know about the conditions before or after the game or anything" (Rough Translation).

The second part is what baffles me. In my understanding, the person is saying that he cannot help imagining it would be good (?) if he could let the players know they don't have to worry about fan service in order to focus on the game as much as possible. Is that, to some extent, correct?

If not, what would be the meaning of this structure, to be more specific, what is the meaning of:

> ようにそっとする.

I know そっとする means roughly 'leave alone', but I've tried searching for examples of it in combinations with ように and couldn't find any samples.

And also, what nuance does たらと思います bring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't contain たらと思います in it. So, I don't address this phrase. If the original passage doesn't have it, probably stachexchange wants you to start another question thread because it's totally unrelated.

Also, I think "集中できろよう" should read "集中できるよう."

So, ように here roughly means "in a way that," "such that," "so that" or the like. It might help you put a comma between ように and そっとしてあげたら. For example,

> Aをしなくてもいいように、そっとしてあげる

roughly means "to leave him alone so he doesn't have to do A." I think the rest of your interpretation is fine.

Comment: well it doesn't contain たらと思います persay, but it does contain たらと思わずにはいられない、which, regardless of the use of the expression ずにはいられない, still contains the construction [conditional たら + quote particle + verb of imagining/thinking]. Or did I get it all wrong?